# How to increase Sensitivity and precision of a measuring sensor?

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, error-analysis, metrology

Considering the definition that

Sensitivity: Relation between the maximum of range, the sensor can $\frac{i}{p}$ to the corresponding $\frac{o}{p}$ given by the sensor due to it.
Ex: A pressure sensor can take a max of $100\space PSI$ and the corresponding $\frac{o}{p}$ it gives is $5\space V$. Then Sensitivity is $\frac{5}{100} \space V/PSI$.

Precision: A definition to quantify repeatability of value of the measurement when measured again and again in the same conditions. Noise reduces the precision of the measurement.

Is it safe to say that:
1) Amplifiers will increase the sensitivity of a sensor.
2) Noise filters will increase the precision of a sensor.

Comment: What are your notations i/p and o/p?

Comment: Input and Output.

Comment: Was it really easier & clearer to type `$\frac{i}{p}$` as opposed to `input`? Is that notation common in electric circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An amplifier will increase the sensitivity of a sensor but will also increase noise pickup. It is also true that a filter is capable of removing noise, and thereby improving precision- but only if the frequency content of the noise is the root cause of non-repeatability in the measurement. Note also that if the signal shares the same frequency range as the filter, then it defeats the amplifier's signal gain.

Comment: Is it right to say that using a parametric amplifier is the best bet, are there better methods to improve sensitivity, not compensating with the noise pickup.

Comment: it depends on the details of the situation- however in general it's best to replace the sensor you have with one of better performance. fewer things can go wrong!